# Extract values from JSON object using standard utilities

Tags: json, bash, sed, grep, jq

I have a txt file and its content is as follows. I am trying leave only value like 12, rachel.howell@reqres.in and delete brackets, quotation mark, comma, and the key. Could someone help me what I miss or go wrong with my command line? Thank you!

```
{
"id": 12,
"email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Rachel",
"last_name": "Howell",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/hebertialmeida/128.jpg",
}
```

Now, the result I can output is that

```
{
    12,
    "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
    "Rachel",
    "Howell",
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/hebertialmeida/128.jpg",
 }
```

What I expected is:

```
12
rachel.howell@reqres.in
Rachel
Howell
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/hebertialmeida/128.jpg
```

Here is my command:

```
sed -e 's/[{]//g' | cut -d':' -f '2' test.txt
```

Comment: If this is a JSON value, why don't you use [tag:jq]?

Comment: as mentioned by @oguzismail,  you also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: `jq` is a good way to achieve what I expected, but I would like to practice using `sed`, `cut` to make the same result =)

Comment: `sed` can manage json files only, if they use simple data structures and then always the same. Pitfalls are recursive data structures or different members/order/datatypes/line breaks. So it is always better to use context sensitive json tools like `jq`.

Comment: By the way I never used sed with the option -e on linux like for grep... is that really needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only wanna use sed cut and grep, I would recommand you that :

```
sed "s/}//g;s/{//g;s/\"//g;s/,//g;s/\ //g" test.txt | cut -d":" -f2 | egrep "..*"
```

But there's way more officient.

--

EDIT : description of the command :

sed "s/}//g;s/{//g;s/\"//g;s/,//g;s/\ //g"

-> removes {}",

cut -d":" -f2

-> only takes the 2nd part

egrep "..*"

-> only takes the lines which contain something

Comment: Why do we put the file name before `cut` instead of putting it at the end of command? Thaks! @ ATR

Comment: @Oscar Sed must have an entry and this one is the file test.txt. Then the pipe "|" gives sed's output to cut and from cut to grep. If you specify the file only for cut, sed won't actually have anything to do with. That's why in your command output there was still the { and }

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! @ATR

Answer (score 2):

With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), it'd be:

```
jq -r '.[]' file
```